# How to use custom fonts in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame, macos-monterey

**Specs:**
MacOS Monterey, Python 3.10.4, Pygame 2.1.2

**Context:**
I'm trying to create a game using the Pygame module in Python. I want to display text on the screen and have figured that part out. What I'm not sure about is if I'm able to use custom fonts. By custom fonts I mean I've downloaded a font in the form of a .ttf file.

**Question:**
Is there any way to use this .ttf file/font in Pygame? I understand there are some built-in fonts like Comic Sans.

Comment: I'm sorry for making a dupe post, I'll delete this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom font with the following code:

```py
font = pygame.font.Font(<font file>, <size>)
```

then render it using

```py
font.render(<text>, True, <colour>)
```

See also https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part5
and https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html